# How to create a simple line graph in VB.NET for a website

Tags: vb.net, graph, web-applications

Has anyone got any suggestions on how I can create a very simple graph for a web application? It is to show energy consumption levels per month for a year at a time.

So basically I want it to look like  (assuming my ASCII works)

> --
>    \ --

Yeah it doesn't so I've changed my open id image to the sample

http://mrbrutal.myopenid.com/

Sorry for the long winded approach - a question for another time - free image hosting by openid (and another site probably)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). There are some nice [usage examples](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/styles.html#chart_margins) that seem to create  what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd take a look at [Google's Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) - it will do exactly what you want with the minimum of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the new [ASP.NET Chart Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new Silverlight charting components from Microsoft. Free and they will render simply images.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a JavaScript dependency, the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/) is pretty nifty.

It's a standard interface to many visualizations, including [linecharts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html), [image-based line charts](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/imagelinechart.html) (uses the Google Charts API), and [many others](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) which may fit your need even better..